# Why do these minor changes to f# linear algebra functions make them so much more performant?

Tags: performance, f#

I am fairly new to programming in f# and while I love a lot about it, one thing that bothers me is how often writing code in what feels like the 'proper' way in f# leads to it being incredibly slow. I have been working on a Neural Network in f# and my code incredibly slow compared to my implementations in other languages. One specific case is the following linear algebra functions:

```
// Dot Product

// Slow
let rec dotProduct (vector1 : float []) (vector2 : float []) : float =

    if vector1 |> Array.length = 0 then
        0.0
    else
        vector1.[0] * vector2.[0] + (dotProduct (vector1 |> Array.tail) (vector2 |> Array.tail))

// Fast
let dotProduct (vector1 : float []) (vector2 : float [])  =
    Array.fold2 (fun state x y -> state + x * y) 0.0 vector1 vector2
```

```
// Matrix Vector Product

// Slow

let matrixVectorProduct (matrix : float [,]) (vector : float[]) : float [] =
    [|
        for i = 0 to (matrix |> Array2D.length1) - 1 do
            yield dotProduct matrix.[i, 0..] vector
    |]

// Fast
let matrixVectorProduct (matrix : float [,]) (vector : float[]) : float [] =
    
    let mutable product = Array.zeroCreate (matrix |> Array2D.length1)
    
    for i = 0 to (matrix |> Array2D.length1) - 1 do
        product.[i] <- (dotProduct matrix.[i, 0..] vector)
    
    product
```

I was wondering if anyone with more f# experience could explain why exactly the second case is faster with each example, in terms of how the computer is interpreting my code. The biggest pain in coding with a high level language like f# is it's hard to know how your code is being optimized and run compared to programming in a low level language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the first code sample:

Your slow `dotProduct` function is doing two things that impact CPU perf, in order of impact:

1. Re-allocating an array each recursive call
2. Not using tail recursion

The 2nd point isn't really that big of a deal from what I measured.

For the second sample:

Your slow version is slow because the F# array expression is not fixed. It needs to allocate and use an enumerator to generate the next item until it's done. In your more iterative code, you've pre-allocated a fixed array and you're just filling it in. This is always significantly faster, and when performance is your concern, mutation and loops is usually a good way to win.

There's another way to speed up your dot product code though: just do a simple loop!

```
let dotProductLoop (vector1 : float []) (vector2 : float []) : float =
    let mutable acc = 0.0

    for idx = 0 to vector1.Length - 1 do
        acc <- acc + (vector1.[idx] * vector2.[idx])
    
    acc
```

You'll notice that `[fold2][1]` more or less does this, but it comes with some marginal overhead.

I threw each approach into a [benchmark](https://gist.github.com/cartermp/62eb2b4345ecf0c49d3f019b18244800) to see some comparative results. As you can see, the loop approach is even faster than the `fold2` call, but both are so much faster than your initial implementation that it's a clear win to take either.

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.13.1, OS=Windows 10.0.19042.1288 (20H2/October2020Update)
AMD Ryzen 9 5900X, 1 CPU, 24 logical and 12 physical cores
.NET SDK=6.0.100-rc.2.21505.57
  [Host]     : .NET 6.0.0 (6.0.21.48005), X64 RyuJIT DEBUG
  DefaultJob : .NET 6.0.0 (6.0.21.48005), X64 RyuJIT
```

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Ratio | Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DotProduct | 320,534.9 ns | 1,738.55 ns | 1,626.24 ns | 1.000 | 480.4688 | 18.0664 | 8,040,000 B |
| DotProductLoop | 625.4 ns | 1.93 ns | 1.71 ns | 0.002 | - | - | - |
| DotProductFold | 1,105.1 ns | 10.77 ns | 10.07 ns | 0.003 | - | - | - |

Another thing you can do, if you're committed to writing recursive code, is to have a private helper function that does tail recursion on `Span` or `ReadonlySpan`:

```
let rec private dotProductImpl (vector1 : Span<float>) (vector2 : Span<float>) (acc: float) =
        if vector1.Length = 0 then
            acc
        else
            dotProductImpl (vector1.Slice(1)) (vector2.Slice(1)) (acc + vector1.[0] * vector2.[0])
```

The function that calls this will perform just as well as the loop that I proposed.